# getting error while taking azure sql backup

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm using below command to take azure sql databse backup, but getting error.

> *** Error exporting database:Database source is not a supported version of SQL Server...tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /Action:Export /SourceServerName:"tcp:xxxxx.database.windows.net,1433" /SourceDatabaseName:DbName /SourceUser:user /SourcePassword:password /TargetFile:C:\backups\backup.bacpac
```

What this mean? even **export data tier application** also throws same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). It seems you are using an old version of SSMS.

Alternatively, you can install a newer version of DacFx. Please download from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56508).

You can also use the Export option of Azure portal. To export to a blob storage account on Azure and then download the bacpac from there.